# Simplifying Excel Formula with Multiple SUMIFs

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with three worksheets titled FY09, FY10, and FY11. I need a count of entries that have one of the following statuses (Column D): Complete, Cancelled. Here is what the function currently looks like:

```
=COUNTIFS('FY11'!D:D,"Complete",'FY11'!F:F,">="&D3,'FY11'!F:F,"<="&F3)+COUNTIFS('FY11'!D:D,"Cancelled",'FY11'!F:F,">="&D3,'FY11'!F:F,"<="&F3) + COUNTIFS('FY10'!D:D,"Complete",'FY10'!F:F,">="&D3,'FY10'!F:F,"<="&F3)+COUNTIFS('FY10'!D:D,"Cancelled",'FY10'!F:F,">="&D3,'FY10'!F:F,"<="&F3) + =COUNTIFS('FY09'!D:D,"Complete",'FY09'!F:F,">="&D3,'FY09'!F:F,"<="&F3)+COUNTIFS('FY09'!D:D,"Cancelled",'FY09'!F:F,">="&D3,'FY09'!F:F,"<="&F3)
```

Why can't I use something like this:

```
=COUNTIF('FY10'!D:D,{"Complete","Cancelled"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little more complex than your pseudo example, but this is about as simple as Excel will allow it:

`=SUM(COUNTIFS('FY10'!D:D,{"Complete","Cancelled"}))`

Comment: COUNTIFS was introduced in Excel 2007.  COUNTIF also works, since there is only one condition, and applies to earlier version of excel too

Comment: @Jason: if you click the hollow checkmark next to it to make it green, that will mark it as answered.

Comment: I thought I had clicked it yesterday, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array formula to simplify it, regrettably I don't think it is as simple as the one you wanted...

This is what occurs to me you could do...

```
=SUM(IF(D:D="Cancelled",1,IF(D:D="Complete",1)))
```

*remmeber to enter the formula with ctrl+shift+enter*